# Hierarchically structured Y-label for barbell ggplots

Tags: ggplot2, tidyverse, gt

```
tibble(Class = c("A","A","B","B"),
       Country = c("UK","US","UK","US"),
       Label = str_c(Class,"-",Country),
       PRE = c(0,1,2,3),
       POST = c(4,5,6,7)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_segment(aes(x=PRE, xend=POST,
                   y=Label, yend=Label), color="green") +
  geom_point(aes(x=POST, y=Label),
             color = "navy") +
  geom_point(aes(x=PRE, y=Label),
             color = "salmon") +
  xlab("shift")
```

I don't like in this code that it repeats the `Class` before each label.
Ideally, I want 2 hierarchical labels for the plot: at higher level `Class`, which then splits for UK and US, so that it's easy to compare the barbells of the two countries for the same class.

Alternatively, is there a way to represent the same structure with a `gt-table`, where one column is the individual barbell of the combination Class and Country??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hierarchically structuring plots with `facet_grid`

#### Generate some toy data

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  Class = rep(LETTERS[1:19], each = 4),
  Country = rep(c("UK","US"), 19),
  Measure = rep(c("Measure_A", "Measure_B"), times = 19, each = 2),
  PRE = sample(0:10, 76, replace = TRUE)
)
```

#### Create a plot

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(POST = PRE + sample(2:5)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = PRE, xend = POST,
                   y = Country, yend = Country), color = 'green') +
  geom_point(aes(x=POST, y=Country),
             color = "navy") +
  geom_point(aes(x=PRE, y=Country),
             color = "salmon") +
  labs(x = "Shift") +
  facet_grid(Class ~ Measure,
             switch = 'y') +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = 'outside',
        panel.spacing.y = unit(0.1, "lines"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This could be a solution, but does not really work properly for two reasons

1 I am already using a horizontal facet, so it is as if there is a third classifying variable, call it "measure". This is not a big problem, since it will split the figure in two halves.

2 I have 19 classes for 2 countries. The dimensions of the facet are very out of scale, with  very large labels and minuscole barbells.

It could work if I micromanage dimensions...

Comment: Hi @GiulioGCantone. I added some extra data to your example to try and demonstrate what this could look like. Its harder to address your concerns with labels and barbell sizes without seeing an example that more closely reproduces the problem. It is definitely possible to adjust point size, line width, and text size.